# When should I use MonadState lens combinators?

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens

I understand that a `MonadState s m` gives me ability to get and update an `s`.

I do not however understand how this state is related to the state used in lens combinators like [assign](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.14/docs/src/Control.Lens.Setter.html#assign). Especially when lens can operate on multiple targets. Also, there are simpler functions like [set](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.14/docs/src/Control.Lens.Setter.html#set) that do not require state.

What are use cases for each of those similar combinators?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend you to read this excellent blog post about using lens within `MonadState`. It gives you examples of how awesome Haskell could be.

http://www.haskellforall.com/2013/05/program-imperatively-using-haskell.html

Regarding your question about difference between `assign` and `set`: `assign` is just a version of `set` that operates inside `MonadState`. That's it. You can observe this fact through implementation.

Let me give some examples.

You can use `set` to just set (sorry for repetition) some *field* of some *object*:

```
ghci> set _2 42 ([0.1, 0.2], 3)
([0.1,0.2],42)
```

If you want to use `assign` you need to call this function inside some `State` context. For example consider next simple function:

```
assignMe :: Int -> StateT ([Double], Int) IO ()
assignMe x = do
    before <- get
    liftIO $ putStrLn $ "before assignment: " ++ show before
    assign _2 x
    after <- get
    liftIO $ putStrLn $ "after assignment: " ++ show after
```

If you now call this function in ghci you can observe result of its execution:

```
ghci> execStateT (assignMe 42) ([0.1,0.2], 3)
before assignment: ([0.1,0.2],3)
after assignment: ([0.1,0.2],42)
([0.1,0.2],42)
```

That's it. `assign` just behaves like `set` except it applies lens to *state*.